# Is it possible to hide (not remove) a PivotItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I have a situation where I am showing a set of `PivotItem`s and (depending on the situation) a favorites one.

I need to be able to hide this pivot when the List containing my favorites is empty - yet it needs to show up when there is something there.

Now, I *could* just remove it, but what about this scenario:

1. Go to the pivot view (no favorite-pivot, since the list is empty)
2. Go to one of the remaining `PivotItem`s and select an item.
3. Select that item as a favorite in its own view
4. Tap the back-button, and return to the pivot-view.

Now there will be no favorites-pivot, and that just isn't good enough.

I have tried to remove it with Visibility="hidden", but VS is complaining about the data context not being specified properly (it is.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't add and remove the `PivotItem` dynamically in your code in response to user events?
The user adds a favorite -> create and add the Pivot item.
The user removes his last favorite item -> remove the Pivot item.

Comment: That would be a good idea, but the pivot item is somewhat hard to recreate (at least it would take an unreasonable amount of code) in code-behind. I guess I could remove it, store it and reinstate it at a later time, though.

Comment: You can remove it immediately after the `InitializeComponent` call. That way the user should not notice it. Another possibility would be to create the XAML UI for the pivot item in the `Resources` section and retrieve it from there.

Comment: True. But there is no way to "hide" it instead of dynamically adding and removing it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would have a list of favorites in that pivot item so my approach would be to bind the visibility of the pivot item to a isEmpty property of the list.

For example, the view would be

```
<PivotItem
  Visibility="{Binding IsNotEmpty,
  Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

and in the viewmodel

```
ICollectionView ItemsSource;
...
public bool IsNotEmpty(){     
    return !ItemsSource.IsEmpty;
}
```

and finally, the converter

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter {

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if(value == null)
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    var isVisible = (bool)value;
    return isVisible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var visiblity = (Visibility)value;
    return visiblity == Visibility.Visible;
}}
```

Converter obtained from [Useful Converters](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/useful-calue-converters)

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned in my original question, this is what I tried to do initially. This doesn't work. Thanks for putting the time in to write a very decent answer though.

Comment: could you add more information about the error that visual studio gives you about the data context?

Comment: my fault - turned out that was ReSharper who decided to underline something it shouldn't have.